Can the roots of two cubic apolar polynomials, each having only real roots, ever be interlaced?
Consider two cubic real polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, each of them having only real roots. If we further assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are apolar, can their roots ever be interlaced? I have a feeling that no, but I am not a 100% sure.
Edit 1: I will briefly describe the notion of apolarity in this edit. Let $n$ be a positive integer. There is a natural non-degenerate pairing between complex polynomials of degree at most $n$. If
$$\begin{align} f(x) &= a_0 + \binom{n}{1} a_1 x + \dots + \binom{n}{i} a_i x^i + \dots + a_n x^n \\
g(x) &= b_0 + \binom{n}{1} b_1 x + \dots + \binom{n}{i} b_i x^i + \dots + b_n x^n \end{align},$$
then the pairing $(f, g)$ is defined by
$$ (f, g) = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} a_i b_{n - i}. $$
Note that the pairing $(-, -)$ is symmetric, resp. skew-symmetric, in its arguments if $n$ is even, resp. odd.
We say that $f$ and $g$ are apolar if $(f, g) = 0$.
At the level of roots, if $u_1, \dots, u_n$ are the roots of $f$ and $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are the roots of $g$ (of course, the roots of $f$ need not be distinct, and similarly for the roots of $g$), then $f$ and $g$ are apolar iff:
$$ \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_n} \prod_{i = 1}^n (u_i - v_{\sigma(i)}) = 0. $$
One interesting fact about apolar theorem is Grace's theorem. If $f$ and $g$ are apolar polynomials, then any circular region containing all the roots of either of them must contain at least one root of the other.
That was my crash-course description of apolarity :). Of course, there are, I am sure, many more known facts about apolarity, I am sure, as the notion is classical, but I am not an expert on the topic.
Edit 2: Note that WLOG (up to possibly interchanging $f$ and $g$ and relabeling the roots), we may assume that
$$ u_1 \leq v_1 \leq u_2 \leq v_2 \leq u_3 \leq v_3.$$
Edit 3: I managed to prove the following.
Theorem: Assume given
$$ u_1 < v_1 < u_2 < v_2 < u_3 < v_3 $$
with the $u_i$ and $v_i$ all real numbers, for $i = 1, \dots, 3$.
Let
$$ f(x) = (x - u_1)(x - u_2)(x - u_3)$$
and
$$ g(x) = (x - v_1)(x - v_2)(x - v_3).$$
Then $f$ and $g$ cannot be apolar.
Proof:
Let
$$ \begin{align}
p_i &= (1 \, u_i)^T \\
q_i &= (1 \, v_i)^T
\end{align}, $$
for $i = 1, \dots 3$. We then define
$$ \omega = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ \Omega = ( p_i^T \, \omega \, q_j ), $$
which is a $3$ by $3$ complex matrix. We note that $(f, g)$ is (up to possibly a factor) nothing but the permanent $\operatorname{per}(\Omega)$ of $\Omega$.
Note that the rank of $\Omega$ is at most $2$, so that its determinant vanishes. We thus deduce that
$$ \operatorname{per}(\Omega) = 2(\Omega_{11} \Omega_{23} \Omega_{32} + \Omega_{13} \Omega_{22} \Omega_{31} + \Omega_{12} \Omega_{21} \Omega_{33}). $$
Since we are assuming that
$$ u_1 < v_1 < u_2 < v_2 < u_3 < v_3, $$
we deduce that $\Omega_{ii} > 0$ for $i = 1, \dots, 3$. We also deduce that if $1 \leq i < j \leq 3$, then $\Omega_{ij} \Omega_{ji} < 0$. We thus see for example that each term between parenthesis on the RHS of the formula for $\operatorname{per}(\Omega)$ (such as $\Omega_{11} \Omega_{23} \Omega_{32}$) is negative. Hence
$$ \operatorname{per}(\Omega) < 0, $$
so that
$$ (f, g) \neq 0, $$
i.e. $f$ and $g$ cannot be apolar, as claimed.
Remark: judging from the proof, I have a feeling the analogous statement does not hold if $n > 3$, meaning that there could possibly be some apolar polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degree $n > 3$ which are strictly interlacing. Can someone possibly prove or disprove this? Does anyone know what happens if $n > 3$?

Sorry, what does "apolar" mean?

@GerryMyerson, I wrote an edit to answer your question.
